# Share credentials between native app and web site

Tags: ios, security, safari, oauth-2.0

An application I'm working on allows users to log into an OAuth-enabled backend. The application is therefore privy only to the authentication tokens and user metadata, not to the user's credentials.

Within the application, users can hit links that open up links in a browser. These resources are also protected by OAuth, and the token obtained during login to the native app is also relevant to the web.

I would like the user's credentials to flow from the native app to the web browser in the standard OAuth manner (by including it as an `Authorization` header).

It seems that Android facilitates this through its [shared credentials](https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/associate-apps-and-sites) feature, but I cannot find an equivalent for iOS. I did find the [shared web credentials](https://developer.apple.com/reference/security/shared_web_credentials) feature, but that seems to require knowledge of the user's credentials.

How can I flow OAuth tokens from my native app through to web browsers that it opens?

Comment: In a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55336027/1768303), we want to share secrets from the web browser to a native app.

Answer (score 16):

Associated Domains and Shared Web Credentials don't seem to be a good approach here.

You have two options:

1. Passing the OAuth Access Token as URL-QueryString-Param to the
   WebBrowser. `https://x.y.z/?access_token=abc` You'll have to manipulate the embedded URLs and assure that your backend understands this.
   Very common and easy approach. Many websites like Facebook and
   Google are passing Access Tokens in the URL.
2. If you're using In-App-Browsers (UIWebView, WKWebView), you can intercept the URL-Request and add the Authorization Header on your own. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25539837/how-to-add-customize-http-headers-in-uiwebview-request-my-uiwebview-is-based-on) for UIWebView and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28984212/how-to-add-httpheader-in-request-globally-for-ios-swift/37474812#answer-37474812) for WKWebView (which is little bit harder than UIWebView)

Comment: or have the browser operate as a client on its own and get its own token at the cost of an extra redirect

Comment: @HansZ. can you explain what you mean saying "have the browser operate as a client on its own and get its own token at the cost of an extra redirect"? thank you very much.

Comment: Sending an access token in the URL is not a secure way to do this even with TLS, since it can be inspected in clear in various places, like browser history, server logs, Referer Header (which is send to third party analytics services for example).

Answer (score 6):

*Technically*, you could just include the token in the URI you pass to the browser.

But this would be insecure:

> **Injection of access tokens**
>
> An additional (and very dangerous) threat
> occurs when clients accept access tokens from sources other than the
> return call from the token endpoint. This can occur for a client that
> uses the implicit flow (where the token is passed directly as a
> parameter in the URL hash) and don't properly use the OAuth state
> parameter. This issue can also occur if different parts of an
> application pass the access token between components in order to
> "share" access among them. This is problematic because it opens up a
> place for access tokens to potentially be injected into an application
> by an outside party (and potentially leak outside of the application).
> If the client application does not validate the access token through
> some mechanism, it has no way of differentiating between a valid token
> and an attack token.
>
> (Source: https://oauth.net/articles/authentication/)

It is also forbidden in the specification:

> Access token credentials (as well as any confidential access token
> attributes) MUST be kept confidential in transit and storage, and only
> shared among the authorization server, the resource servers the access
> token is valid for, and the client to whom the access token is issued.
>
> (Source: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-10.3)

So instead, you could try using an alternative OAuth flow, called "Authorization Code Flow", where instead of passing the token to the browser, the app passes a special code, which the browser then uses to obtain a token from the server.

However, your use case isn't exactly what this mechanism was created for, so I'm not sure using it to accomplish what you're after would be in line with the specification.

Answer (score 2):

First you should use HTTPS protocol - google for: let's encrypt (in order to get a free SSL certificate)

The flow you should consider:

1. A user opens up your mobile app and is prompted for their username
   or email and password.
2. You send a POST request from your mobile app to your API service
   with the user’s username or email and password data included (OVER
       SSL!).
3. You validate the user credentials, and create an access token for
   the user that expires after a certain amount of time. (google for: api rate limiting)
4. You store this access token on the mobile device, treating it like
   an API key which lets you access your API service.
5. Once the access token expires and no longer works, you re-prompt the
   user for their username or email and password.

On the server side you should use stuff like: fail2ban, iptables and make sure that the linux version that you use is up to date. (you should update/upgrade from time to time)

On the web application (api) you should validate and serialize all the data. Never send more data that is needed and never accept partial data from the client. On the api application you should do xss (cross site scripting)/csrf (cross site request forgery) prevention. Take a look at OWASP TOP 10 - https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-Top_10 . You should also use security headers - https://www.dionach.com/blog/an-overview-of-http-security-headers on the web api.

Never trust user input.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use built-in apple func & libraries ?

Take a look at [shared web credential](https://developer.apple.com/reference/security/shared_web_credentials)

> To enable shared credentials in your app, add the com.apple.developer.associated-domains key to your app’s entitlements. You can add this entitlement using the target’s capabilities pane (see Figure 1).

or using [iCloud Keychain](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/01introduction/introduction.html).

> This document concentrates on the use of Keychain Services to store and retrieve passwords. Read this document if your application needs to handle passwords for:
>
> Multiple users—for example, an email or scheduling server that has to authenticate many users
>
> Multiple servers—for example, a banking or insurance application, which might have to exchange information with more than one secure database server
>
> **A user who needs to enter passwords—for example, a web browser, which can use a keychain to store the passwords a user needs for multiple secure web sites**

Hope it may help